# Retrieve SQL Server 2008 Product Key

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008

I am trying to obtain the SQL Server 2008 Product key from an installed instance on Server 2008 Std. The previous company never passed us the details and we need to install on a new server to decommission the current one. Does anyone know if this can be found?
Can anyone help with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this. Might help you: http://www.branchbits.com/blog/2010/01/sql-server-2008-product-key/